# How do I add preprocessor defines in Code Composer Studio 4?

Tags: c-preprocessor, code-composer

I have an external text file with some preprocessor defines. How can I integrate them in my CCS project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For CCSv5

**Project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols**

Under the tap Symbols you can put your defines

One thing to note: remember to press the "**Show advanced setting**" in the bottom left corner, or else the **C/C++ General** does not show up

Comment: Thank you for adding info on `Show advanced settings`, I have been wondering how people got the C/C++ to show. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could copy/past in compiler settings : Menu **Build properties > compiler > preprocessor > defines.**

Answer (score 0):

For CCSv8

**Project -> properties -> Build -> MSP430 Compiler -> Predefined Symbols**